# pop up confirmed + alert in javascript

Tags: javascript

how do I make confirmed pop up by alert for user's data in form, for example :confirmed box: dear (user name) are you sure? alert box: thanks for submission (user name)

Comment: `confirm(message)` and `alert(message)`. What's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help documents before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

There are the functions `confirm` and `alert`:

```
username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
confirm("dear " + username + " are you sure?"); 
alert("thanks for submission, " + username);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, did you already take ["the tour"](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)? Have fun :-)